# Accessing oracle database via SID through JDBC without host:port

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I'm looking for information on how to connect to an oracle database via JDBC, I only find the same solutions which show how to connect with a known host:port. I have to pass this connect string

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@[host][:port]:SID
```

to JDBC and this works.

```
protected Connection connect()
{
    Connection conn;

    try
    {
        Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1536:sid", "user", "passwd");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return conn;
}
```

The problem with this approach though is, that I have to find out on which host:port the database is. When I use database tools like `PL/SQL Developer` or others, they don't need this. The user is only prompted for the database name and the the tool can somehow connect nevertheless. SO I would like to know how this is done. Currently I achieve this by requiring that `tnsping` is in the path, and in my helper class (not shown in the above example code), which provides the connect URL, I call `tnsping` and parse the output. This is not really a good method, and I was wondering if there is a proper way to connect.

Comment: The are no magic here.  `tnsping` searches for ip:port inside your local `tnsnames.ora` file.  You can do the same.

Comment: Yes, of course I can do the same. I was not asking for an alternative to access this, I wanted to know if there is an official way of doing this. Parsing tnsping oputput or tnsnames directly is not really different.

Comment: This is not an "alternative" way.  This is the only way.  You can either read `tnsnames.ora` manually or ask external program (such as `tnsping`) to do it for you.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Thanks, this was not entirely clear for me and I thought I had missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not able to do using normal JDBC (thin driver).  You may try using OCI, which [apparently](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/urls.htm) will understand TNS entries.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I tried to use an oci connect string, but now I get the following error `no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path`.

Comment: @Devlous : This require Oracle client dlls in path (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html).  Frankly, your just fine with your current solution.

Comment: OK, Thanks! I thought there should be some better way than to fiddle in oracle config files, but if that's the way it is.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a given ORACLE_SID, database tools like SQL Developer get the rest of the information from your `tnsname.ora` file located at `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`. This file contains the rest of the connection information like

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)
```

The JDBC driver doesn't look for this file and hence won't connect just by giving the SID.

*Reference:*
[Tnsnames.ora - Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora)